# Call to undefined method MY_Loader::_ci_load_library()

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm new to Codeigniter, and currently I just installed Codeigniter 2.2.0 with HMVC and ORM Datamapper version 1.8.2 .

I'm sure I have installed the ORM correctly, but when I test the Link, It give me this

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DM_Loader::_ci_load_library() in ...\application\third_party\MX\Loader.php on line 173
```

and, this is what inside loader.php

```
if ($path === FALSE)
        {
            $this->_ci_load_library($library, $params, $object_name);
        }
```

I'm sure had rename some protected in `third_party/MX/Router.php` and had added the code in `index.php` some codes below

```
/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 *
 */
require_once APPPATH.'third_party/datamapper/bootstrap.php';
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

your answer is my enlightment. thank you.

Comment: Could you please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28927450/unable-to-load-libraries-when-using-ci-3-with-hmvc

Maybe you have wrong verison of HMVC

Comment: Please follow the steps from existing answer: [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39631967/4246397)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened the file and went to line 173 and changed

```
$this->_ci_load_library($library, $params, $object_name);
```

to

```
$this->_ci_load_class($library, $params, $object_name);
```

to match the only loading class I could see in the parent class CI_Loader that would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Need change some field of Session Variables in *`config.php`* (application/config/config.php)

```
$config['sess_driver']         = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name']    = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']     = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path']      = 'ci_sessions';;
$config['sess_match_ip']       = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```